# can't Creating a site in Crafter CMS 3.1.0

Tags: docker, docker-compose, crafter-cms

Unable to Create site getting error notification

I followed the instructions given here : https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/getting-started/quick-start-guide.html

Steps followed:

I cloned Crafter CMS Docker Compose repo from GitHub and then 
I started the container from authoring directory using the  docker-compose up command
And then I tried to Create a site in Crafter Studio but I got error notification which says "Unable to Create site: contact system administrator"

I am using Docker Desktop Community in my windows 10 64 bit

Docker - Version 2.0.0.3 (31259)
Crafter CMS - Version 3.1.0
OS - Windows 10 64 bit
Browser: Google Chrome

I expected site creation but I got error notification which says "Unable to Create site: contact system administrator"

Error Nofication :

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is RAM. You need to give it 8GB+ of RAM to be able to start all the services (including Elasticsearch).

More on this issue here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/craftercms/Ei7gJGTEE4I

Also more on the requirements for the authoring env: https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/system-administrators/activities/authoring/authoring-env-performance-tuning.html